# Store weekday as NSDictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, dayofweek

I'm looking for some advice as to how to store opening and closing times in an object model.

Right now I'm using objective c but I suppose this question would apply to any programming language.

Off the top of my head I came up with a quick solution to store the days as keys to an NSDictionary (Map for java users), whose values are another dictionary with 2 keys: open & close.

This might do the job but I'm hoping to get some advice for a better implementation, maybe using calendar components?

This is important as the stored weekdays and times will undergo some processing later on and strings might not be the best idea...

```
        @"monday":
    @{
        @"open":@"9:00",
        @"close":@"17:00"]
    },
```

Suggestions are most appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: opening and closing hours for a shop. I have a shop custom object defined (NSObject subclass), now I'm looking for the best way to store the opening and closing times...

Comment: What about custom objects/class?

Comment: you can use NSIntegers to store the number of minutes from 00:00 (that is if you need to do manipulations on the time itself). You can add then add NSNumbers to the Dictionary

Comment: What do you want to know??  Certainly you can do it, and it will work just fine.  You have a choice as to how you store the times.  Probably either a string as you show, or an integer (NSNumber) number of minutes since midnight -- whichever is more convenient to you, as the space/performance issues would be almost identical.

Comment: @Larme I do have a custom object defined.

Comment: @HotLicks space & performance are not issues. Or maybe performance is only somewhat of an issue... But what I'm interested in is the PROPER way to handle this that would also save both space and processing time as a result... and would make a good model

Comment: @YuviGr: Be consistent with everything that MacOS X and iOS do, and store times or time differences as double in seconds.

Comment: Store the time values in a fashion that will be most convenient to the code, while consistent with techniques used elsewhere in your app.  There is no single "right" answer -- programming is an art.